# How to get row info from two tables based on the column value of first table

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

TableA

```
article_id | attribute_id
1          | 5
2          | 6
```

TableB

```
attribute_id | attribute_name
5            | foo
6            | bar
```

How would I get the corresponding row if I only know the article id? So if I pass article_id 1 I get:

```
article_id | attribute_id | attribute_name
1          | 5            | foo
```

I know I could do it with two separate queries but was wondering if it could be done in one? I thought about using INNER JOIN ON but article_id isn't in both tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure, you can (and have to) use `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT TableA.article_id, TableB.*
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.attribute_id = TableB.attribute_id
WHERE TableA.article_id = 1
```

The `SELECT` part let us retrieve `article_id` from the first table, and all fields from the second one.
The `INNSER JOIN` clause joins rows that have the same `attribute_id` from the two tables.
The `WHERE` condition let us select only the row with `article_id = 1` in first table.

Answer (score 2):

Use NATURAL JOIN - [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join)

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA NATURAL JOIN TableB
WHERE article_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  select article_id, tablea.attribute_id,attribute_name 
  from tablea,tableb where    
  tablea.attribute_id=tableb.attribute_id
  and article_id= :passedId
```

Answer (score 0):

Join using attribute_id

```
SELECT * FROM TableA A, TableB B where
A.attribute_id = B.attribute_id
```